# Video functionality in Liferay 7

Tags: ckeditor, liferay-7

I need to add video functionality to CKeditor. Thus, enabled Xuggler plugin. However, it has some limitations. Thus, searched about other plugins which can be integrated with CKeditor and supports video content.

Following are the findings for above: -

1. I found online ckeditor builder which gives video functionality (CKEditor 4). Please help in integrating the same with Liferay 7.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder.

2. I got another plugin html5video; https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/html5video
   Please help in integrating the plugin with CKEditor available with Liferay 7.

Thus, requesting you to help in accomplishing either of the above solution in order to achieve video functionality in Liferay 7 webcontent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the lfr-dxp-src/modules/apps/foundation/frontend-editor/frontend-editor-ckeditor-web module. It contains all the CKeditor related code.

Froma quick look over it it seems that you should focus on 2 things:

**Get the plugin code.**

You would need a fragment bundle for that that will inject the necessary JS into the frontend-editor-ckeditor-web.

Look here for insperation: *lfr-dxp-src/modules/apps/foundation/frontend-editor/frontend-editor-ckeditor-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/_diffs/plugins/media*

**Probably you will need to change the configuration of the CKEditor**

You need to create an edit options contributor. Make sure that you put this in a separate module form the fragment as the fragment.

Look here for inspiration: *com.liferay.frontend.editor.ckeditor.web.editor.configuration.CKEditorConfigContributor*